# How do I get next Thursday from a random date?

Tags: excel, calendar, excel-formula

What I want to do is so you have a list of random dates, it will never be the same so it has to be a universal formula, but you get any date, any date of the year and then every Thursday is the Starting of a new week. For each date you set the date equal to the Thursday that it is greater than the previous and less than the Thursday.

Example to clarify since I am being vague, say you get June 24th, 2012. June 24th is greater than June 21st, 2012 (which is the previous Thursday) and it is less than June 28th, 2012, which is the next Thursday. This means it should generate the value June 28th, 2012 in the column next to it.

Is that making any sense? Based on any date value you get, you calculate which Thursday date it should generate? Any way to do this in excel?

Comment: perhaps if you provided more examples, we could get a better idea of what you're wanting.

Comment: Do you want a random date for each week where your weeks are defined from Thursday to Thursday? OR you want a random date then the next date should be the following Thursday? Then repeat?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This formula will give you the Thursday following a date in A1

`=A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1+2)`

If A1 is a Thursday it returns that date, if it should be A1+7 if A1 is Thursday then change to this version

`=A1+8-WEEKDAY(A1+3)`

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1) < 5, A1+5-WEEKDAY(A1), A1+5+7-WEEKDAY(A1))
```

Will give you the next Thursday from the date given in Cell A1 in Excel.  If the input date is a Thursday, it will give the next Thursday.

Use <= in the conditional if you want to display the input Thursday when given a Thursday, rather than displaying the next Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been answered perfectly, however I just want to share some code that might help anyone who is looking for something more robust other than only "Thursday" or "Tuesday". But rather would like to pass a function a date, and the day Name, and get back the next date that occurs. Its a two part function

```
    Function nextDateofDay(ByVal xdate As Date, ByVal dayOfWeek As String) As 
     Date
      dow = findWeekDayNum(dayOfWeek)
      nextDayofWeek = xdate + 7 - Weekday(xdate + 7 - dow)

     End Function



     Function findWeekDayNum(ByVal dayName As String)
        dayName = Trim(UCase(dayName))
        daysOfWeek = Array("SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", 
                            "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY")
        'Need to find the day of week of that name, so looping through array
        For j = LBound(daysOfWeek) To UBound(daysOfWeek)
             If daysOfWeek(j) = dayName Then
                 findWeekDayNum = j + 1 ' need to add one cause array index 
                     'starts at 1
                 Exit Function
              End If
        Next j

     End Function
```

And then how to use one would simply would use the function by

```
   sub test()
       currentDate = now() ' or can be a date from a cell
       dayDesired = "MONDAY" ' or can also be from a cell
       nextDate = nextDateofDay(currentDate,dayDesired)
       debug.print(nextDate)
   end sub
```

Answer (score -1):

For new Java 8 Time API, you can use below code. You need to change `DayOfWeek.THURSDAY` etc in the below code.

```java
LocalDate date1=LocalDate.now();
// This will give you int value of Day(for eg. Friday) and the date you want to check for

int duration=DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY.getValue()-date1.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
System.out.println("duration "+duration);
if(date1.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY)) {
    System.out.println("Wednesday");
} else {
    date1=date1.plusDays(7).minusDays(7-  duration); 
}
// it will first give next day of week then minus the duration from 7.

System.out.println("new date1 "+date1);
```