# "how to find the next Friday after adding 2 days to a date?"

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that returns Friday's date for the previous Thursday - Wednesday.  My sales week closes on every Wednesday, but posts on Friday. 
Example - If I enter any date between 8/11 and 8/17, I want the formula to return 8/19. A date of 8/18 should roll to the following end of week 8/26.

Comment: You could rephrase the question to, "how to find the next Friday after adding 2 days to a date?"

Comment: This works: `=A1+9-WEEKDAY(A1+3)`. (Modified from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255074/how-do-i-get-next-thursday-from-a-random-date))

Comment: Thank you!!!! It works:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=A1+9-WEEKDAY(A1+1,15)
```

[image]

Comment: Where R5 =11/2/2016, I used this formula  =R5+10-WEEKDAY(R5+2,15) and it returned 11/11.  I need 11/4.

Comment: It works everywhere, but the Wednesday dates. Those post this week, where Thursday starts the following Friday's postings.