# What is the excel formula to find the upcoming Saturday a month?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, spreadsheet, formulas

I need to add a formula to my spreadsheet as a date. However the date needs to update automatically as it is the first Saturday of the upcoming month.

So the formula should return 05/08/2017 as is the upcoming first Saturday of the month, then after that date it should change to 02/09/2017.

Also, how would I then alter the formula to find the 2nd/3rd Saturday of the month?

Comment: Have you even tried or do you want us to make it for you?

Comment: See what you can do with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255074/how-do-i-get-next-thursday-from-a-random-date

Comment: I have tried, obviously.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. I suggest reading through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+7-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+7)
```

[image]

---

If you want it based on the current date, find the next first Saturday:

```
=TODAY()+7-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+7)
```

This will find the **next** first saturday of the month.  So on the 6th of this month it will return `2/9/2017`

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, this returned the first Saturday of September, not the upcoming first Saturday of the month at present which is 05/08/2017.

Comment: You said "update automatically as it is the first Saturday of the **upcoming month**" The upcoming month is September not August.  @NicholasNicolaou  Do you want the current month?

Comment: I apologise, I have updated the question. Yes Scott, and then after that date passes it should change to 02/09/2017 and so on.